# Filtrar itens por categoria com angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular-6

sou nova no angular, e preciso fazer uma filtragem. Eu tenho uma listagem de programas e quero filtrar esses programas através de um menu. Por exemplo, no menu terão as categorias: futebol, blogs, esportes...
Quando eu clicar na categoria "futebol" eu quero que na lista tenha apenas os programas correspondentes a futebol, e assim por diante. Como eu consigo fazer essa filtragem com angular+2?

menu:

```
<div *ngIf="(programs$ | async) as programs; else: loading">
  <ul class="c-programs__nav">
    <li *ngFor="let program of programs; let i = index">
      <a href="#" class="c-programs__link">{{ program.name }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

listagem:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let program of programs; let i = index">
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let program of programs; let i = index">
    <div
      class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"
      *ngFor="let program of program.programs"
    >
      <h2 class="c-programs__title">{{ program.name }}</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

json:

```
    [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Programas",
    "base_Url": "http://uol.com.br",
    "order": 0,
    "programs": [
      {
        "id": 56,
        "name": "Programa 1",
        "base_Url": "https://google.com",
        "active": true,
        "menu_id": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 57,
        "name": "Programa ",
        "base_Url": "https://google.com",
        "active": true,
        "menu_id": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 58,
        "name": "Programa",
        "base_Url": "https://google.com",
        "active": true,
        "menu_id": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Jornalísticos",
    "base_Url": "http://uol.com.br",
    "order": 1,
    "programs": [
      {
        "id": 59,
        "name": "Programa 2",
        "base_Url": "https://google.com",
        "active": true,
        "menu_id": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 60,
        "name": "Programa ",
        "base_Url": "https://google.com",
        "active": true,
        "menu_id": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 61,
        "name": "Programa",
        "base_Url": "https://google.com",
        "active": true,
        "menu_id": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: depende da quantidade de informações que pode ter nesse array, vc pode ter que organizar pelo backend, mas se for pouca coisa pd fazer pelo front msm, vc pode usar pipe para isso

Comment: procura por pipe filter